# Create columns for specific "other tags" of OSM PBF files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, fields-attributes, pbf

When downloading PBF files of Openstreetmap via Geofabrik, the file contains a field called "other_tags" which includes all the OSM tags for this feature. It is a String field and looks like `"cycleway"=>"track","lit"=>"yes","maxspeed"=>"30","sidewalk"=>"both","source:maxspeed"=>"DE:zone30","surface"=>"asphalt"`.

I now want to create new columns for only some specific tags. Lets say "cycleway" and "maxspeed". I need to do this in QGIS.

Comment: The .pbf file should not have such a tag. I rather believe that you are reading OSM data through the GDAL OSM driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html. For saving the cycleway and maxspeed tags as separate attributes you should edit the osmconf.ini file.

Comment: Thanks, then QGIS uses this driver when opening pbf files. Did not know that. You can add this as answer if you wish to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the plugin [QuickOSM](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) for this purpose. After you have installed it, go to `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\QuickOSM\resources\ogr\to_be_modified_osmconf.ini` and open the .ini file with a suitable texteditor like Notepad++. Search for the line called `attributes=` within the desired geometry type and add your desired attributes separated by comma. For example: `attributes=name,highway,waterway,aerialway,barrier,man_made,maxspeed,access,foot,vehicle,bicycle,tunnel,bridge`. Save the file.

[image]

Now open QuickOSM and navigate to "OSM File". Choose your file to open, the desired geometry type and set your OSMConf file you have just modified. Click open. (If you did not create a new .ini file and just override the original file, there is no need to set it, because it is the default file).

[image]

The file will now load with the fields you have just specified and the associated values.